# How to reduce duplication in the build-depends fields of a .cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Here's a .cabal file:

```
Name:                myprogram
Version:             0.1
-- blah blah blah
Cabal-version:       >=1.9.2

Executable myprogram
  HS-source-dirs:       src
  Main-is:              Main.hs
  Build-depends:        attoparsec == 0.10.*,
                        base == 4.3.*,
                        -- long long list of packages

Test-Suite test
  HS-source-dirs:       test, src
  Type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Main-is:              Main.hs
  Build-depends:        attoparsec == 0.10.*,
                        base == 4.3.*,
                        -- long long list of packages
                        QuickCheck == 2.4.*
```

Is there any way I can replace the long list of build-depends packages for the test suite with "same as for the executable, plus QuickCheck"?

**Edit:** version information.

- cabal-dev 0.9
- cabal-install 0.10.2
- Cabal library 1.10.2.0
- GHC 7.0.4
- Haskell Platform 2011.4.0.0

Comment: Your cabal file is structured in an unfoavourable way, leading to a lot of re-compilation and also introducing the dependency duplication you mention. You can make your tests/executables depend on your library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305970/how-to-make-a-haskell-cabal-project-with-libraryexecutables-that-still-run-with/12305972#12305972. Starting from there, you can move as much into the direction @Toxaris pointed out in his answer, if you like that.

Comment: There are [plans](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2832) to add a `common` field to the .cabal format where e.g. shared `build-depends` can be specified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since version 2.2 Cabal supports common stanzas, to dedup *build info* fields:
https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html#common-stanzas

```
cabal-version:       2.2
name:                myprogram
version:             0.1
-- blah blah blah

common deps
  build-depends: base ^>= 4.11,
                 -- long long list of packages
  ghc-options: -Wall

library
  import: deps
  exposed-modules: Foo

test-suite tests
  import: deps
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Tests.hs
  build-depends: foo
```

Answer (score 35):

**NOTE:** superseded by phadej's answer suggesting common stanzas.

---

> Is there any way I can replace the long list of build-depends packages for the test suite with "same as for the executable, plus QuickCheck"?

Not that I know of. However, there is a way to only mention the list of `build-depends` packages once, by structuring your project into three targets:

1. a library that contains all your code, and needs the long build-depends list.
2. an executable that consists of only one file, and depends on base and the library from above.
3. a test-suite that depends on the library from above, and the testing packages you are using.

Maybe this approach is what indygemma's answer proposes, but the Cabal file proposed there will not quite achieve it, as Norman Ramsey points out in a comment. Here's the main points of what you need in a Cabal file. For a full example that works for me, you can look at [this Cabal file](https://github.com/Toxaris/pts/blob/master/pts.cabal).

```
name: my-program
version: ...

library
  hs-source-dirs: src-lib
  build-depends: base, containers, ...
  exposed-modules: My.Program.Main, ...

executable my-program
  hs-source-dirs: src-exec
  main-is: my-program.hs
  Build-depends: base, my-program

test-suite tests
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs: src-test
  main-is: tests.hs
  other-modules: ...
  build-depends: base, my-program, test-framework, ...
```

Important points:

- There are three separate source directories for the three targets. This is necessary to stop GHC from recompiling library files when building the other targets.
- All of the application code is in the library. The executable is just a wrapper, like this:

  ```
  import My.Program.Main (realMain)
  main = realMain
  ```
- The library exposes all modules that are necessary for testing.

The last point highlights the drawback of this approach: You end up having to expose internal modules. The main benefit of this approach is that you have less duplication in the Cabal file, and maybe more importantly, less duplication in the build process: The library code will be built only once, and then linked into both the executable and the test-suite.

Comment: In Cabal-1.26 (as yet unreleased), it will be possibly to replace the `library` stanza with `library my-internal-lib`, which makes an internal library called "my-internal-lib" which is only internally visible to components in your package, and not other users. See https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/3022

Comment: OTOH, I think exposing internals is okay, so long as it has a suitable name like `Internal` or `Base`.

Comment: You know, i tried this approach, and it was failing when using the same directory for libraries and executables. So i think that having a separated directory is somehow necessary for this to work. The failure led to a message telling me to add dependencies to the `build-depends` section of the library, even though they were there

Comment: Yes, as written in the answer, you have to use different source directories for the library and for executables.

Comment: In the example cabal file you mention, the test-suite section still lists "containers", "mtl", etc while the library section already lists them, too. Isn't this exactly what OP tries to omit? I am asking this because I run into a similar trouble: Importing `Data.Map` in a test suite file does not compile without listing `containers` in the test suite section even though `containers` is already listed in the library section. The error msg is "Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Map.Strict’"

Comment: You have to list the packages that the tests themselves depend on.

Answer (score 5):

You could also consider using [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack#readme) instead of writing the .cabal file by hand:

In hpack's package.yaml format, you can specify a common `dependencies` field whose entries are added to every components' `build-depends` field when generating the .cabal file.

For example, see hpack's own [package.yaml](https://github.com/sol/hpack/blob/master/package.yaml) and the generated [hpack.cabal](https://github.com/sol/hpack/blob/master/hpack.cabal).

To start using hpack with an existing package, you can use [hpack-convert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpack-convert) which will generate the package.yaml from an existing .cabal file.

To create a new package that uses hpack, you can use stack's `simple-hpack` template like so: `stack new mypkg simple-hpack`.

If you use [stack](https://haskellstack.org) for development, you don't have to call `hpack` manually to regenerate the .cabal file from an updated package.yaml – stack will do that automatically.

Answer (score -1):

No easy way:

- you can use [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) and specify your dependencies once, but then you will need to reprocess your Cabal file through m4 whenever you change it.
- you can move the code you are testing out to a library, and then specify the library in your Build-depends for the test. That requires you to install a library even just to run the test.
- You can just not put the test in the cabal file at all. Build it with ghc --make, which will pull in dependencies. But then you lose cabal integration.

Answer (score -5):

There is an optional **library** section for .cabal files, which solves your problem.

```
name:              myprogram
version:           0.1
-- blah blah blah
cabal-version:     >=1.9.2

library
    build-depends: attoparsec == 0.10.*
                 , base == 4.3.*
                 -- long long list of packages

executable myprogram
    hs-source-dirs: src
    main-is:        Main.hs

test-suite test
    hs-source-dirs: test, src
    type:           exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:        Main.hs
    build-depends:  QuickCheck == 2.4.*
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I build I get an error message that starts ``Implicit import declaration:
    Could not find module `Prelude':
      It is a member of the hidden package `base'.``

Comment: You still need to depend on base and anything that the `Main.hs` uses

Comment: This answer is totally not working for me. Using Cabal version 1.10 I'm just having to write everything in *triplicate*.