# Eliminating repetition in cabal files

Tags: haskell, cabal

I often have similar properties in many stanzas of my `.cabal` files. E.g.

```
Library x
    ...
    ghc-options:
       -O2 -Wall -fno-warn-missing-signatures -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
       -fno-warn-name-shadowing

Executable y
    ...
    ghc-options:
       -O2 -Wall -fno-warn-missing-signatures -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
       -fno-warn-name-shadowing
```

Keeping them consistent is tedious and error-prone. Is there a better way?

Even trickier is when the fields are similar but not exactly the same e.g. when I have several executables which have common build dependencies but small variations.

Comment: I don't think there's currently any good solution. Two options to bypass this problem in parts are: (A) use multiple `ghc-options` fields per component (yes, that's possible), thereby making the shared options completely identical and the differences easier to maintain; and (B) generate your Cabal file from some other source that does not contain redundant information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce duplication in the build-depends fields of a .cabal file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163604/how-to-reduce-duplication-in-the-build-depends-fields-of-a-cabal-file)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163604/how-to-reduce-duplication-in-the-build-depends-fields-of-a-cabal-file

Answer (score 2):

I think that `cabal` does not provide that functionality. I've also wondered about this some time ago. You can see [my comment on Johan Tibell's blog as well as Johan's answer to it](http://blog.johantibell.com/2012/04/cabal-bench.html?showComment=1351087383653#c3552556086157441246).

Answer (score 1):

I have written a tool to make it easier to specify Cabal files in Haskell, which helps deal with this issue and a few others.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cartel