# cabal misconfiguration for tests

Tags: haskell, cabal, hspec

My `.cabal` file contains the following hspec configuration:

```
-- The name of the package.
name:                MyModule

version:             0.1.0.0

cabal-version:       >=1.10
...
test-suite my-tests
  ghc-options:         -Wall -Werror
  cpp-options:         -DTEST
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             HSpecTests.hs
  hs-source-dirs:      tests
  build-depends:       MyModule, base >= 4.8 && < 4.9, containers >= 0.5 && <0.6, split >= 0.2 && < 0.3, hspec
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
MyProject
     | - src
          | - Main.hs
          | - Other.hs
          | - tests
             | -HSpecTests.hs
     | - dist
     | - MyProj.cabal
```

when I run `cabal build`, my source build succesfully to an executable `./dist/build/myproj/myproj`.

`cabal build` then fails with:

```
cabal: can't find source for HSpecTests in
dist/build/my-tests/my-tests-tmp, tests
```

Inspecting the `build` directory shows that the `my-tests` directory is missing.

changing the `hs-source-dirs` to `src/tests`
produces:

```
cabal: can't find source for HSpecTests in 
dist/build/my-tests/my-tests-tmp, src/tests
```

While moving all tests to the top level under root/tests, and changing the `.cabal` file to `hs-source-dirs:  tests` produces:

```
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id MyModule-0.1.0.0-inplace
    (use -v for more information)
```

How have I misconfigured this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hs-source-dirs` is wrong:

```
 hs-source-dirs:      tests
```

Given that `HSpecTests`'s path is `src/tests/HSpecTests.hs`, it should be

```
 hs-source-dirs:      src/tests
```

However, keep in mind that `tests` are usually in the top-level folder:

```
MyProject
     | - src
          | - Main.hs
          | - Other.hs
     | - tests
          | -HSpecTests.hs
     | - dist
     | - MyProj.cabal
```

Comment: changing hs-source-dirs to src/tests produces the message:
cabal: can't find source for HSpecTests in
dist/build/my-tests/my-tests-tmp, src/tests

Answer (score 0):

There was two things wrong:

1) (thanks to @Zeta for getting me on track with my file structure), the tests needed to be in a tests directory at the root level

2) As documented here: [Error while creating test suites: "cannot satisfy -package-id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803725/error-while-creating-test-suites-cannot-satisfy-package-id) my tests could not depend on an executable and required the creation of a library