# Shared cabal "build-depends" (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, cabal

In my cabal project, I define a `library`, an `executable`, and a `test-suite`. They share many `build-depends` entries and it is tedious to keep them all in sync. How do I define a common set of dependencies which they can share?

Comment: There does not seem to be a way. The answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163604/how-to-reduce-duplication-in-the-build-depends-fields-of-a-cabal-file) might help you move in the right direction, though.

Comment: @madjar Actually, looking at the top answer to that question I rather like the style of separating the lib, executable(s), and tests into separate source trees.  It helps separate concerns and would enforce better modularity.